# How do I remove a non-present drive from the list?

Tags: drive

When I got this new PC, it had a floppy drive attached. Recently I decided that I wasn't going to need it, ever, and it only made some noise on startup. So I took out the cables connected to it, and it no longer makes noise obviously. Problem solved. But Nautilus still shows the floppy drive in the list of drives, and I can't get rid of it despite it not actually being present. It is also shown on the launcher. Clicking it does nothing. How do I remove these buttons?

This is what `sudo fdisk -l` gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 203.9 GB, 203928109056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24792 cylinders, total 398297088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdc4bdc4b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            4096   398297087   199146496   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120033041920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234439535 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c1b44

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   234438655   116968449    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   234438655   116968448   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 113.3 GB, 113330094080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13778 cylinders, total 221347840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 6442 MB, 6442450944 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 783 cylinders, total 12582912 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

It doesn't appear to contain any info on floppy drives or missing drives.

And this is what `cat /etc/fstab` says:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4ce4e749-7286-46d6-b756-cb09cb51fead /boot           ext2    defaults            0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

It does say something about a floppy drive, but nothing about it being missing, defunct, or anything like that.

Comment: what does `cat /etc/fstab` say in the console? Please include it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should definitely remove your floppy drive from `fstab`, you can use a simple text editor for this. If this does not solve your problem in itself (it should though), please refer to this [old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/29712/134964) for a similar question.

If it is a desktop PC, another option is trying to disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: I commented the line about /dev/fd0, do I need to reboot for it to take effect?

Comment: Probably a relog is enough, but it won't hurt to reboot.